# How to check if email already exist in angularjs using spring boot

Tags: angularjs, spring

I think I almost found a solution to my problem but I still need a bit of tweaking.

I have an `@RestController` where I do this to check if the user exists or not

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/email")
public Boolean getByEmail(@RequestBody String email) {
    String userId;
    try {
        User user = userDao.findByEmail(email);
        userId = String.valueOf(user.getId());
        LOGGER.info(user.toString());
        LOGGER.info(userId);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        LOGGER.info("email does not exist");
        return false;
    }
    LOGGER.info("Email does exist");
    return true;
}
```

In AngularJs I did something like this:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('RegisterController', RegisterController);

    RegisterController.$inject = ['UserService', '$http' ];
    function RegisterController(UserService, $http) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.register = register;

        vm.error="This is a sample Error";

        function register() {

            testEmail();
            console.log(vm.user)
            console.log(("email must been verified before this"))

            //if the testEmail returns false Create a user else give an error
           // vm.dataLoading = true;
           // UserService.Create(vm.user)

        }

        function testEmail(){
            console.log("Check email")
            console.log(vm.user.email)
            console.log($http.post('/email',vm.user.email))
            return $http.get('/email',vm.user.email)
        }
    }

})();
```

What I basically want to do is find a way that the `testEmail` function returns `true` or `false`?

Comment: you can't , use the `$http` promise that is returned

Comment: Other approach is to use Angular form validation, namely async validators for this purpose. That has the benefit that you can inform user that the email is already used or not (for instance when the email field loses focus).

Comment: I will look into async validators or could you give a quick example on how to do this using this case??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest looking into the async validators like one of the comments said, but if you don't like that option here is some more information.

The problem is that since the testEmail function makes an asynchronous ajax request, the lines following the call will run before the ajax request has completed. You need to wait until the request has completed. See the example below:

```
    function register() {

        //test email returns a promise object, you need to wait until it is resolved, passing the response from the server to the callback
        testEmail().then(function(response){

            //replace this with the appropriate response
            if(response.data.valid){
                console.log(vm.user)
                console.log(("email must been verified before this"))

                //if the testEmail returns false Create a user else give an error
                // vm.dataLoading = true;
                // UserService.Create(vm.user)
            }

        });

    }
```

Comment: I should also note, this example doesn't include proper error handling around the request since I only passed one callback function inside the .then. See the angular $http docs for more information on how to set up better error handling: [angular $http docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: I will accept this answer because this is a possible solution. But i'm going to validating the form with the async validators. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of using async validators:

## Form

```
<form name="form" ng-submit="!form.$pending && form.$valid && vm.register()">
  <label>Email</label>
  <input ng-model="vm.user.email" email-not-used ng-model-options="{ debounce: 500 }" type="text" name="email" />
  <div ng-messages="form.email.$error">
    <div ng-message="emailNotUsed">User with this email already exists.</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Few things to note here:

- `!form.$pending && form.$valid && vm.register()`: this basically ensures that you can only submit the form (register the user using `vm.register()`) if the form is valid and no validation is pending (because of asynchronous validations).
- `ng-model-options="{ debounce: 500 }`: This ensures that the validations will not be called on every key press, but 500 ms after last key stroke and no other activity
- `email-not-used` is the async validation directive defined in the next step
- [`ngMessages`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages) are used to display error message
- You should ideally add validations for email format, check if the email is not empty and so on. I've omitted them to keep the example simpler

## JavaScript

```
app.directive('emailNotUsed', function($http, $q) {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      ngModel.$asyncValidators.emailNotUsed = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        return $http.get('/email', viewValue).then(function(response) {
          return response.data == true ? $q.reject('Email is already used.') : true;
        });
      };
    }
  };
});
```

Also note that while I've used similar code before, I wrote it from memory and not tested it in this example. You might get some errors, so some tweaking might be required. But it should give you the general idea.

Comment: Wow thanks for this nice example an explaining what the stuff does.